# Error MSB4025. The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.1

I have created a fresh NUnit project based on .net core 2.1.

When I run command `dotnet test project1.dll` in windows machine then its working fine but when I am trying to run same command in red hat linux machine (rhel 8), then it is giving error that "**The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1**". I look into solution in internet that you need to update your SDK but I want to use dotnet core 2.1 only and I could not found any command to install higher release version of dotnet core 2.1 in linux.

Please let me know if any prefer solution for this problem available.
Below is my project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Below information about SDK given by dotnet --info command on linux.

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.518
 Commit:    c9b5af2ec4

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     rhel
 OS Version:  8
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         rhel.8-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk/2.1.518/

Host (useful for support):
 Version: 2.1.22
 Commit:  23677d3ee7

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.518 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.22 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Note: I do not want to run test command using csproj file. I have requirements to run dotnet test command only using dlls.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue? I am also facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for the `dotnet vstest` command: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-vstest)

You can use it like this: `dotnet vstest project1.dll`

Comment: It worked. I still do not get the reason, `dotnet test` was working in windows and not in Linux distros. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: You may have a different version of the Dotnet SDK on Linux, in newer versions, you can use `dotnet test` on both assemblies and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Believe that clearing all Nuget packages then restoring the .sln will resolve it.

To clear all Nuget packages, go to Tools -> Options
[image]

To restore the solution, right-click on the .sln then restore.
[image]