# Visual Studio Build Fails due to Error: MSB4025

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, command-line-interface

Hi I am trying to run `dotnet build <Sln file>` to build the project but I am getting this error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

**Build Failed**

Folder Structure: C:\Users\USERNAME\PROJECTNAME\Folder0\File0.vdproj(1,1)

Dotnet Version: 6.0.301

Comment: The `dotnet` CLI does not support `vdproj` files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error MSB4025. The project file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903302/error-msb4025-the-project-file-could-not-be-loaded-data-at-the-root-level-is-i)

Answer (score 0):

I think that this information is useful.

> vdproj is a MSI creation project for Visual Studio. Its been deprecated and most people have moved on to either WIX or NSIS or a professional grade installer creation tools such as Install Shield. If you do not require an installer for your product just exclude the vdproj project from the solution and continue with your life. For fun if you want to try to transition right away to wix, try this powershell script https://github.com/chrisoldwood/vdproj2wix

[Visual Studio - vdproj is incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028746/visual-studio-vdproj-is-incompatible)

> MSI setup (.vdproj)   This project can't be opened in Visual Studio 2013 because it doesn't support that project type. We recommend that you use InstallShield Limited Edition for Visual Studio (ISLE), a free deployment solution that directly supports most Windows platforms and application runtimes. You can also use ISLE to import data and settings from Visual Studio Installer projects.

[Port, migrate, and upgrade Visual Studio projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/porting/porting-migrating-and-upgrading-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#MSIsetup)